# How can I find the first child from Firebase ref?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get the first child from a firebase ref?

My firebase data is:

root
-users
--userid
---projects
----projectid
-----pivots

I can get a logged in users' projects like this:

`this.$bindAsArray('projects', db.ref('users').child(this.auth.user.uid).child('projects'))`

At this stage I need to get the pivots from the first project from the list of this.projects.

How can I do that?

I can get them after selecting a project from a v-for but I need them on initial load.

`<tr v-for="project in projects" v-on:click="selectProject(project)">`

```
selectProject: function (project) {

this.selectedProject = project;

    this.$bindAsArray('pivots', db.ref('users').child(this.auth.user.uid).child('projects').child(this.selectedProject['.key']).child('pivots'))

  },
```

Comment: Are you writing or reading data?

Comment: readin @frank-van-puffelen